# HTML page loads slowly unless I omit one of three linked static files

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the page's `head` tag I use 3 external files (CSS, Font, jQuery Library):

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Poppins font -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As I use all the 3 - Page loads very slow. If I omit **one of them (no matter which one)** - page loads immediately. Why is that?

Comment: More external scripts = more requests to fetch them = more waiting time for them to download = page loads slower

Comment: @IvanS95 As I know browser downloads 2 external files as once. So "never" download more than 2 -  to avoid this?

Comment: There's a minifed version of `jquery-ui` at `//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css`.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend giving this a read, it might help a lot with this kind of issues: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the scripts are being loaded synchronously one after the other.

**How to make them load faster?**

If there is no dependency between the scripts and links load them asynchronously:

**Asynchronously loading JS scripts**

For that you can use [async](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) attribute. 
From the docs:

> When present, it specifies that the script will be executed
>   asynchronously as soon as it is available.

Example:

```
<script src="demo_async.js" async></script>
```

Like @IvanS95 mentioned below -  you can also use [defer](http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/).

**Asynchronously loading CSS links**

You can use [preload](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/link-rel-preload).

Fro the docs:

> Resources loaded via  are stored locally in the
>   browser, and are effectively inert until they’re referenced in the
>   DOM, JavaScript, or CSS. For example, here’s one potential use case in
>   which a script file is preloaded, but not executed immediately, as it
>   would have been if it were included via a  tag in the DOM.

An example:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="preload" as="style">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the js file at the end.

```
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- Poppins font -->
</head>

<body>
...
...

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to run your site against - https://www.webpagetest.org/ excellent resource.

Also, I would cache the data for 365 days that way they do not have to call your external scripts again.

To learn about caching check out this site - https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching

And you can always use your F12 Browser tools to see the waterfall effect of loading all the elements of your Web page.